# How to view the foreign keys relationships on a DB table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I know that in order to view the uniqueness of a table you use something like this

```
set serveroutput on;
BEGIN
    <DB name>.show_uniqueness('BILL_BASE.<Table name>');
END;
```

and this gives you all unique constraints on the table you intend to modify.

My question is how to view all foreign keys associated with a table. Is there a query like the  one above that i can use to view such information

Answer (score 1):

You can query user_constraints view to list all constraints defined on your tables. Foreign key constraints have type R:

```
select constraint_name
      ,table_name
  from user_constraints
 where constraint_type = 'R'
```

Column R_CONSTRAINT_NAME will give you the primary key constraint for the other table. Using the same view but now for the PK constraint will give you information about the related table.